# Filtering function works once , after that displays empty box

Tags: javascript, html

Thanks for any help you can give me.

The following problem I present to you is this :

***A JavaScript filter for an HTML gallery works fine on the first try. After  new settings are applied to the filter it displays nothing.***

---

**This is the HTML gallery :**

*Only a div called gallery with some children, which have an image and some data attributes.*

```html
  <div id ="CaixaGaleria" class="gallery">
    <div data-estilo="Pintura a óleo" data-ano="2004" data-tamanho=""><img src="/Imagens/Screenshot_20200728_064349.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div data-estilo="Pintura a óleo" data-ano="2004" data-tamanho=""><img src="/Imagens/Screenshot_20200727_224457.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div data-estilo="Pintura a óleo" data-ano="2003" data-tamanho=""><img src="/Imagens/Screenshot_20200725_233940.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div data-estilo="Lápis"          data-ano="2000" data-tamanho=""><img src="/Imagens/quadra-mar.260x300.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div data-estilo="Pintura a óleo" data-ano="2002" data-tamanho=""><img src="/Imagens/Filme/2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div data-estilo="Pintura a óleo" data-ano="2002" data-tamanho=""><img src="/Imagens/Screenshot_20200727_224457.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div data-estilo="Pintura a óleo" data-ano="2003" data-tamanho=""><img src="/Imagens/Screenshot_20200725_233349.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div data-estilo="Pintura a óleo" data-ano="2000" data-tamanho=""><img src="/Imagens/Screenshot_20200725_233129.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div data-estilo="Lápis"          data-ano="2005" data-tamanho=""><img src="/Imagens/Filme/Screenshot_20200725_233110.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
```

---

**This is the HTML filter:**

*Only a  `<select>` element with some options to match the gallery images data-attributes (style , year and size) :*

```html
<div id="SearchBar">
    Filter according to the following options:<br><br>

  <label for="Estilo">Estilo:</label><br>

    <select name="Estilo" id="Estilo">
      <option value="vazio" >-</option>
      <option value="Pintura a óleo">Pintura a óleo</option>
      <option value="Retrato">Retrato</option>
      <option value="Lápis">Lápis</option>
      <option value="Aguarela">Aguarela</option>
      <option value="Ilustrações">Ilustrações</option>
    </select><br><hr>

  <label for="Ano">Ano:</label><br> 

    <select name="Ano" id="Ano">
      <option value="null"> -  </option>
      <option value="2005">2005</option>
      <option value="2004">2004</option>
      <option value="2003">2003</option>
      <option value="2002">2002</option>
      <option value="2001" >2001</option>
      <option value="2000">2000</option>
      <option value="1999">1999</option>
    </select><br><hr>

    <label for="Dimensões">Dimensões:</label><br>

    <select name="Dimensões" id="Dimensões">
      <option value="null">-</option>
      <option value="pequeno">10*15 a 35*40</option>
      <option value="medio">35*40 a 50*50</option>
      <option value="grande">50*50 a 80*90</option>
      <option value="XXL">80*90 a 100*120</option>
    </select><br><hr><br>

<button onclick="filtrar()">Search</button>
```

---

**This is the JavaScript that runs when I click on the button Search.**

*Checks If the image data-attributes match the selected option. If they match image should be displayed, if they dont display should be  `<"none">`.*

```js
let Galeria = document.getElementById("CaixaGaleria").children;
let FilterEstilo = function(){return document.getElementById("Estilo").value}
let FilterAno = function(){return document.getElementById("Ano").value}
let FilterDimensões = function(){return document.getElementById("Dimensões").value}


 function filtrar(){
    for (let i = 0; i < Galeria.length; i++) {
        if (Galeria[i].getAttribute("data-estilo") == FilterEstilo() && Galeria[i].getAttribute("data-ano") == FilterAno() && Galeria[i].getAttribute("data-tamanho") == FilterDimensões())
        Galeria[i].style.display = "inline-block";
        else if(Galeria[i].getAttribute("data-estilo") !== FilterEstilo()  && Galeria[i].getAttribute("data-ano") !== FilterAno() && Galeria[i].getAttribute("data-tamanho") !== FilterDimensões())
         Galeria[i].style.display = "none";
    }
        };
```

Okay , now this works when I click on the button the first time.

The problem is that when I choose new options , it doesnt display the filtered options. In fact , it displays nothing.

I know I'am probably missing something but I don't know what.

Comment: Your `else if` is pretty all-encompassing. You sure you want to use `&&` for all of those conditions?  Have you stepped through this code in your debugger to see what's actually happening?

Comment: _"now this works"_ - How? o.O The `data-*` attributes are all lower-case in the markup but not in your script and you use attributes that aren't in the markup.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, thanks for pointing that out , it's fixed.  Althought it still worked somehow , perhaps because I was only using the 1st filter but still the main issue remains.

Comment: @Marc You're right , those many conditions are creating some issues. If I drop down some of the conditions , the filter starts working properly.

Answer (score 1):

What i suggest to you is to refactor a little your code to make it easier to read and better see eventual errors

First, avoid using special chars on variables and functions like `FilterDimensões`

Then, instead of having multiple function that does the same thing like `FilterEstilo` , `FilterAno` and `FilterDimensões`, declare a generic function to get value by tag id :

```
function getFilterValue(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id).value
}
```

Then your `filtrar` function contains redundant code, instead of test if values are the same as filter AND values are not same as filter, i suggest you to reset all your elements to `display:block;` then hide the not matching datas. And, btw, get your filter values in vars inside filter function.

```
function filtrar(){

    let filterEstilo = getFilterValue("Estilo")
    let filterAno = getFilterValue("Ano")
    let filterDimensoes = getFilterValue("Dimensoes")

    for (let i = 0; i < Galeria.length; i++) {
        Galeria[i].style.display = "inline-block";
        if(Galeria[i].getAttribute("data-estilo") !== filterEstilo  && Galeria[i].getAttribute("data-Ano") !== filterAno && Galeria[i].getAttribute("data-Dimensões") !== filterDimensoes)
            Galeria[i].style.display = "none";
    }
 };
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input. Those are good advices!

Answer (score 0):

first thing try always to write a clear code, that help you to find the error :
so here in your html make the empty options value "" note null because null here is a caractere :

```
<div id="SearchBar">
    Filter according to the following options:<br><br>

  <label for="Estilo">Estilo:</label><br>

    <select name="Estilo" id="Estilo">
      <option value="" >-</option>
      <option value="Pintura a óleo">Pintura a óleo</option>
      <option value="Retrato">Retrato</option>
      <option value="Lápis">Lápis</option>
      <option value="Aguarela">Aguarela</option>
      <option value="Ilustrações">Ilustrações</option>
    </select><br><hr>

  <label for="Ano">Ano:</label><br> 

    <select name="Ano" id="Ano">
      <option value=""> -  </option>
      <option value="2005">2005</option>
      <option value="2004">2004</option>
      <option value="2003">2003</option>
      <option value="2002">2002</option>
      <option value="2001" >2001</option>
      <option value="2000">2000</option>
      <option value="1999">1999</option>
    </select><br><hr>

    <label for="Dimensões">Dimensões:</label><br>

    <select name="Dimensões" id="Dimensões">
      <option value="">-</option>
      <option value="pequeno">10*15 a 35*40</option>
      <option value="medio">35*40 a 50*50</option>
      <option value="grande">50*50 a 80*90</option>
      <option value="XXL">80*90 a 100*120</option>
    </select><br><hr><br>

<button onclick="filtrar()">Search</button>
```

and for js file change it like this :

```
  let galeria = document.getElementById("CaixaGaleria").children;

  let filterEstilo = function (el) {
    let estilo = document.getElementById("Estilo").value

    if (!estilo) {
      return true
    } else {
      return el.getAttribute("data-estilo") == estilo
    }

  }

  let filterAno = function (el) {
    let ano = document.getElementById("Ano").value
    if (!ano) {
      return true
    } else {
      return el.getAttribute("data-ano") == ano
    }

  }
  let filterDimensões = function (el) {
    let dimension = document.getElementById("Dimensões").value
    if (!dimension) {
      return true
    } else {
      return el.getAttribute("data-tamanho") == dimension
    }

  }


  function filtrar() {

    for (let i = 0; i < galeria.length; i++) {

      if (filterEstilo(galeria[i]) && filterAno(galeria[i]) && filterDimensões(galeria[i])) {
        galeria[i].style.display = "inline-block";
      } else {
        galeria[i].style.display = "none";
      }

    }
  }
```